# Web-based Grep app

Tags: open-source, web-apps, self-hosted, text-processing, plain-text

I am looking for an application I can host at my house on one of my servers that allows me to grep large datasets.

I have roughly 10-15 TB of txt files. I am currently using a GUI-based grep application on my desktop and it takes next to forever to run.

I have a few servers with 60+ gigs of RAM and about 16 TB of space.

I was wondering what would be a good recommendation for this? I have tried ELK and it worked on and it ran fine but would quickly run out of space.